# improve execution time in a for loop (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, output, lapply

Here is a reproducible example of a for loop. Since I want to do 3000 iterations and my matrix is way bigger than this reproducible example, the computer crushes. Any ideas on how can I do it?

I have read that loops are not reccomended in R and instead the web proposes to use vectors and apply functions but I wasn't able to build my formula with that functions...

The matrix:

```
row.names <- c('A2003','B2010','C2011','D2010','E2001','F2005','F2009','G2003','G2007','H2004','H2010')
sp1 <- c(4,83,1,2,4,3,1,5,7,2,4)
sp2 <- c(5,0,2,3,10,5,0,2,4,3,1)
sp3 <- c(7,2,4,8,7,2,4,83,1,5,7)
sp4 <- c(0,2,4,2,4,12,1,5,7,2,4)
Site <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','F','G','G','H','H')
Year <- c('2003','2010','2011','2010','2001','2005','2009','2003','2007','2004','2010')
Obs <- c(1,1,1,4,9,6,8,2,5,2,3)
ID <- c('A2003','B2010','C2011','D2010','E2001','F2005','F2009','G2003','G2007','H2004','H2010')
df<- data.frame(row.names, sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, Site, Year, Obs, ID)
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df[,1] <- NULL
df
df.1 <- subset(df, Obs == 1)
df.more <- subset(df, Obs >= 2)
df.1
df.more
```

The loop function:

```
require (vegan)    
iterations <- 3000
out <- vector("list", iterations)
for(i in 1:iterations){      
  rnd.more <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df.more, df.more$Site),
                                      function(df.more) df.more[sample(nrow(df.more), 1,replace=FALSE) , ])
  )
  rnd.df <- rbind(df.1,rnd.more)                                   
  rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[1:4], method="bray"))  
  rnd.df.bc[lower.tri(rnd.df.bc,diag=TRUE)] <- NA
  triang <- rnd.df.bc[!is.na(rnd.df.bc)]
  mean.bc <- mean(triang)
  out[[i]] <- list(rnd = rnd.df, bc = rnd.df.bc, ave = mean.bc)
}
```

Extraction of the results:

```
all.rnd.df <- lapply(out, "[[", "rnd")
capture.output(all.rnd.df,file="all.rnd.df.txt")

all.rnd.df.bc <- lapply(out, "[[", "bc")
capture.output(all.rnd.df.bc,file="all.rnd.df.bc.txt")

all.triang <- lapply(out, "[[", "ave") 
capture.output(all.triang,file="all.triang.txt")
```

Comment: Remark: R allows specifying function names as strings but this is type system subverting nonsense, don’t do it; use the function name directly. In your case, this means: write \``[[`\` instead of `"[["`.

Comment: Where does vegdist come from?

Comment: @A. Idigoras, please note that your example isn't truly reproducible if you don't include all the necessary packages. `vegdist` comes from the `vegan` package.   Once I figured that out, the example ran fine though.

Comment: Hi @Heroka, I'm using vegdist (method="bray") from vegan package because I want to create a matrix of similarity based on the species (columns from 1 to 4) for each iteration.

Comment: You can move a lot of your operations out of the iteration loop. For example, why sample every time in the loop when you can create a list of sampled indices just once and reference that inside your loop. Same with your `rbind`s. You can create one master `data.frame` and just pass it the pre-sampled indices.

Comment: Hi @Zelazny7. I tried to do so at the beginning but the thing is that the sampling I want is complicated: I want to get different matrices containing both prefixed specific samples (in this case the samples from df.1) plus random unique observations from the df.more matrix. And that’s why I used the loop. But, I'm trying to run your proposed script now to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

precompute the sample indices:

```
idx <- lapply(1:iterations, function(x) {
  tapply(1:nrow(df.more), as.character(df.more$Site), function(y) {
    if(length(y) == 1) y else sample(y, 1)
  })
})

idx <- lapply(idx, function(ids) c(1:nrow(df.1), ids + nrow(df.1)))
```

precompute a placeholder `data.frame to index`

```
rnd.df <- rbind(df.1, df.more)
```

now you just index the precomputed objects without having to calculate them every loop:

```
iterations <- 3000
out <- vector("list", iterations)
for(i in 1:iterations){      
  rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[idx[[i]] ,1:4], method="bray"))  
  rnd.df.bc[lower.tri(rnd.df.bc,diag=TRUE)] <- NA
  triang <- rnd.df.bc[!is.na(rnd.df.bc)]
  mean.bc <- mean(triang)
  out[[i]] <- list(rnd = rnd.df, bc = rnd.df.bc, ave = mean.bc)
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
f1 = my method
f2 = OPs code

> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times=5L)
Unit: seconds
 expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
 f1()  2.21069  4.877017  4.666875  5.27416  5.444411  5.528096     5
 f2() 13.54813 13.554965 19.500247 14.51089 27.074520 28.812732     5
```

#### Make it parallel:

```
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

out <- foreach(i = 1:iterations, .packages=c('vegan')) %do%
{
  rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[idx[[i]] ,1:4], method="bray"))  
  rnd.df.bc[lower.tri(rnd.df.bc,diag=TRUE)] <- NA
  triang <- rnd.df.bc[!is.na(rnd.df.bc)]
  mean.bc <- mean(triang)
  list(rnd = rnd.df, bc = rnd.df.bc, ave = mean.bc)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: So this is working pretty good, @Zelazny7. Thank you! Now I find another problem also with the function capture (the last part of my script)... Again the computer crushes at this point. Any more ideas?

Comment: I would try using `sink`. It can still take a while, but I will often write 100k lines of converted model code to a file: `sink("test.txt"); lapply(out, \`[[\`, "rnd"); sink()`

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with the `vegan` package, I'm a little limited in what advice I can give you.  For the most part, you've constructed your `for` loop well and as you can see below, you don't gain much by converting it to a function and running it through `lapply`.

I think your best bet is to parallelize your code.  In the example below, if you convert your `for` loop to a function and use `parLapply`, you can shave a couple seconds off if you include the cluster build time.  If you exclude the cluster build time, it's about 5 times faster on my 7 cores.  Changes in computational time will vary by the number of cores you can run on.  But I think that may be your best option for now.

```
library(parallel)
library(vegan) 

row.names <- c('A2003','B2010','C2011','D2010','E2001','F2005','F2009','G2003','G2007','H2004','H2010')
sp1 <- c(4,83,1,2,4,3,1,5,7,2,4)
sp2 <- c(5,0,2,3,10,5,0,2,4,3,1)
sp3 <- c(7,2,4,8,7,2,4,83,1,5,7)
sp4 <- c(0,2,4,2,4,12,1,5,7,2,4)
Site <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','F','G','G','H','H')
Year <- c('2003','2010','2011','2010','2001','2005','2009','2003','2007','2004','2010')
Obs <- c(1,1,1,4,9,6,8,2,5,2,3)
ID <- c('A2003','B2010','C2011','D2010','E2001','F2005','F2009','G2003','G2007','H2004','H2010')
df<- data.frame(row.names, sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, Site, Year, Obs, ID)
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df[,1] <- NULL
df
df.1 <- subset(df, Obs == 1)
df.more <- subset(df, Obs >= 2)
df.1
df.more

more.fun <- function(df.more, df.1)
{
  rnd.more <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df.more, df.more$Site),
                                      function(df.more) df.more[sample(nrow(df.more), 1,replace=FALSE) , ])
  )
  rnd.df <- rbind(df.1,rnd.more)                                   
  rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[1:4], method="bray"))  
  rnd.df.bc[lower.tri(rnd.df.bc,diag=TRUE)] <- NA
  triang <- rnd.df.bc[!is.na(rnd.df.bc)]
  mean.bc <- mean(triang)
  list(rnd = rnd.df, bc = rnd.df.bc, ave = mean.bc)
}

start.orig <- Sys.time() 
  set.seed(pi)
    iterations <- 3000
    out <- vector("list", iterations)
    for(i in 1:iterations){      
      rnd.more <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df.more, df.more$Site),
                            function(df.more) df.more[sample(nrow(df.more), 1,replace=FALSE) , ])
        )
      rnd.df <- rbind(df.1,rnd.more)                                   
      rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[1:4], method="bray"))  
      rnd.df.bc[lower.tri(rnd.df.bc,diag=TRUE)] <- NA
      triang <- rnd.df.bc[!is.na(rnd.df.bc)]
      mean.bc <- mean(triang)
      out[[i]] <- list(rnd = rnd.df, bc = rnd.df.bc, ave = mean.bc)
  }
end.orig <- Sys.time()

start.apply <- Sys.time()
  fn = out <- lapply(1:3000, function(i) more.fun(df.more, df.1))
end.apply <- Sys.time()


start.parallel <- Sys.time()
  cl <- makeCluster(7)
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library(vegan))
  clusterExport(cl, c("df.more", "df.1", "more.fun"))
start.parallel.apply <- Sys.time()
  out <- parLapply(cl, 1:3000, function(i) more.fun(df.more, df.1))
end.parallel <- Sys.time()


#* Compare times
end.orig - start.orig
end.apply - start.apply
end.parallel - start.parallel
end.parallel - start.parallel.apply
```

(the time comparisons here are pretty crude)

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, I'm trying to do it with my data. While the script is running I would like to make you a question about the cluster. Why did you choose 7 cores? When I do it I get this error:
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: group length is 0 but data length > 0

Comment: I have eight cores on my computer.  I often use 7 cores to leave one open for other stuff I'm doing (e-mail, etc, while I wait).  You'd have to check how many cores are on your machine.